# Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO AuditRecord 
    (AuditActionId
    ,EntityName
    ,EntityKey
    ,CreateUser
    ,CreateDate)
OUTPUT inserted.AuditRecordId INTO #InsertedArEmailAndStatus 
SELECT 
    2 /* update */
    ,'CustomerContact'
    ,ContactId
    ,CURRENT_USER
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM #UpdatedEmailAndStatus
```

in `#InsertedArEmailAndStatus` there are 3 columns. 
In `#UpdatedEmailAndStatus` there are 4 columns, but in `AuditRecord` I am inserting 5 columns so where do I add the 5th column? Either in `#InsertedArEmailAndStatus`  or in `#UpdatedEmailAndStatus` maybe?

Comment: Either name only one column in the destination table of your OUTPUT clause or OUTPUT three columns worth of data.

Comment: Also, for those playing along at home, I believe MSG 213 is incorrect number of columns.

Comment: i tried output for 3 columns its still the same error

Answer (score 2):

Your actual problem is that you are not passing enough values to `#InsertedArEmailAndStatus` try this (replace col2, col3 with columns that you want to store in EmailAndStatus table)

```
INSERT INTO AuditRecord 
    (AuditActionId
    ,EntityName
    ,EntityKey
    ,CreateUser
    ,CreateDate)
OUTPUT inserted.AuditRecordId, Inserted.Col2, Inserted.col3 
INTO #InsertedArEmailAndStatus 
SELECT 
    2 /* update */
    ,'CustomerContact'
    ,ContactId
    ,CURRENT_USER
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM #UpdatedEmailAndStatus
```

Comment: Or alternatively, `OUTPUT inserted.AuditRecordId INTO #InsertedArEmailAndStatus (OneColumnName)`